# Postgres - UPDATE ON CONFLICT not-null constraint violation

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to use `UPDATE .. ON CONFLICT` available from `Postgres 9.5` but I have a problem with violating null constraint on id.

I get:

> ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "feed" violates not-null constraint

Basically when `id = null` *(feedId)* I would like to perform **INSERT** and if id is returned to run an **UPDATE**.

Also I have `WHERE` clause in that query that it should be used only when there is an ID and not use when not because when adding it I also got an error that `column reference \"id\" is ambiguous`. It there a fix to my query or there is an alternative?

Without WHERE clause UPDATE is working and INSERT is not. But in the original case I posted below I have trouble with both errors.

I am new with writing sql queries and solutions I found online did not helped me with my case.

```
"INSERT INTO feed (id, team_id, name, url, auto_approve, last_pulled_at, source, evergreen)
 VALUES (:feedId, :teamId, :name, :url, :autoApprove, :lastPulledAt, :source, :evergreen)
 ON CONFLICT (id)
 DO UPDATE SET
    id = :feedId,
    team_id = :teamId,
    name = EXCLUDED.name,
    url = EXCLUDED.url,
    auto_approve = EXCLUDED.auto_approve,
    last_pulled_at = EXCLUDED.last_pulled_at,
    source = EXCLUDED.source,
    evergreen = EXCLUDED.evergreen
 WHERE id = :feedId
 AND team_id = :teamId"
```

Comment: 1) Postgres 9.5 is 5 months past EOL 2) Is this `...WHERE id = :feedtId...` a typo as elsewhere you have `:feedId`? 3) If `:feedId` is indeed `NULL` and the `id` column is `NOT NULL` then this will not work as it will trip the `NOT NULL` constraint as you have found.  4) Is the `id` column defined as some sort of `sequence`/`identity`? **Add answers as update to question**

Comment: That should have been Postgres 9.5 is a 1 year and 5 months past EOL.

Comment: Also where is this query being run? I'm trying to figure out how the  `:<some_name>` naming works?

Comment: :<some_name> are params for bindValue I have in the code.. And yes, id, or feedId is identity object of the specific feed (if sent through request). So if it is sent through request then that object exists in the db and then update the query and if not the insert new row.. Maybe there is other way to write what I am trying to accomplish? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Well if you are trying to get around the `NOT NULL` constraint then this will not work as that is checked before the rest of the statement is executed. Is the `default` value for the `id` column some sort of `autoincrement`? Probably best to include the table definition. As per my previous request add the information **as update to question**.  People should not have to walk through the comments to get relevant information.